# Cannot insert datetime from csv into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, csv, sql-insert

I am trying to get a "datetime" from a csv file and insert it into MySql Database. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $date = new Datetime();
                $this->date->format('Y-d-m H:i:s', ($data[3]));

                $sql = "INSERT INTO logs(ID, User, Flag, Date) values('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]')";
                $insert = $this->dataBase->getData($sql);
```

Comment: You appear to be formatting the date but not passing it into the string.

Comment: `$date` !== `$this->date`... not to mention that if `$this->date` is a DateTime object, then the format() method syntax is wrong.... read the friendly manual

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you give me an example on how to do it please? I would really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`$date` is different from `$this->date` that is why you are getting the error :

```
Notice: Undefined property: Import::$date Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the value of date formating and the format have to be Y-**m**-d not Y-d-**m**:

```
$date = new Datetime($data[3]); 
$myDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO logs(ID, User, Flag, Date) values('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$myDate')"; 
$insert = $this->dataBase->getData($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let [MySQL](http://www.mysql.org) handle the [date formatting](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) for you:

```
 INSERT INTO logs(ID, User, Flag, Date) values('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', DATE_FORMAT('$myDate', '%d %b %Y %T:%f'));";
```

You may also want to look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) and prepared statements, so as to avoid SQL injection.